# How to parse CRS from shapefile using geotools

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, geotools

I need to retrieve CRS from a shapefile. I have tried to get it using `getCoordinateReferenceSystem()` which is provided by [org.geotools](https://www.geotools.org/). My code is as follows.

```
URL someURL = new URL("https://github.com/basilmohammed/CRS-Extraction-From-ShapeFile/raw/master/ShapeFiles/3857/3857-Point/3857Point.shp");
ShapefileDataStore SHPdataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(someURL);
ContentFeatureSource featureSource = SHPdataStore.getFeatureSource();
ContentFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features();
SimpleFeatureType schema = featureSource.getSchema();
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = schema.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
// the coordinates system I want to reproject the data to
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
//Define a MathTransform object
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
```

But always I am getting **sourceCRS** with `null` as follows.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Shapefiles ***ought*** to have a `.prj` metadata file, but it isn't required, so `null` is a valid result.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say that it was because you were opening the `.prj` file instead of the `.shp` file but surprisingly it works (because you are creating the `ShapefileDatastore` directly). The code you provided works just fine for me, except that it appears that, that shapefile is actually in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) already so the `.prj` file is wrong.

#### My Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.geometry.MismatchedDimensionException;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;

public class FetchCRS {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException,
      MismatchedDimensionException, TransformException {
    URL someURL = new URL(
        "https://github.com/basilmohammed/CRS-Extraction-From-ShapeFile/raw/master/ShapeFiles/3857/3857-Point/3857Point.shp");
    ShapefileDataStore SHPdataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(someURL);
    System.out.println(SHPdataStore);
    ContentFeatureSource featureSource = SHPdataStore.getFeatureSource();
    ContentFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();
    SimpleFeatureType schema = featureSource.getSchema();
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = schema.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
    System.out.println(sourceCRS);
    // the coordinates system I want to reproject the data to
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    // Define a MathTransform object
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature type = iterator.next();
        Geometry defaultGeometry = (Geometry) type.getDefaultGeometry();
        System.out.println(defaultGeometry);
        System.out.println(JTS.transform(defaultGeometry, transform));
      }
    }

  }

}
```

#### Output

```
ShapefileDataStore [file=https://github.com/basilmohammed/CRS-Extraction-From-ShapeFile/raw/master/ShapeFiles/3857/3857-Point/3857Point.shp, charset=ISO-8859-1, timeZone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]], memoryMapped=false, bufferCachingEnabled=true, indexed=true, fidIndexed=true]
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere", 
  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", 
    DATUM["D_WGS_1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS_1984", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator"], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH]]
POINT (77.39083006594812 23.27470458279848)
POINT (0.0002090802286007 0.0006952136549894)
...
```

Thus the first point (`POINT (77.39083006594812 23.27470458279848)`) is transformed to `POINT (0.0002090802286007 0.0006952136549894)` which is probably not what you want.

If I switch to `.../ShapeFiles/4326/4326-Point/point.shp` and transform to EPSG:3857 I get:
`POINT (77.39083006594812 23.27470458279848)` -> 
`POINT (8615107.79501011 2665273.4881518427)` which looks plausible.

Comment: Actually, you were right. Accidently I changed the file to `.prj`. I have edited the code in which the way I have tried. Even then I was getting the same error. My `sourceCRS` was null.

Comment: Then the code you are running is not the same as the code you posted, as it works for me

Comment: Yes, I posted the question with a wrong URL. I have edited and made it in right way. Now can you have a try and check? It is getting **null** value only

Comment: there must be some difference between your code and mine (which I have added) as it works for me