# Parsing CRS from different shape files (.tab, .mif, .shx, .kml)?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I have various shape files (.tab, .mif, .shx, .kml) and would like to parse crs from them.

I found below link which was helpful to parse .shx files, but this code cant parse rest of the files. [How to parse CRS from shapefile using geotools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359967/how-to-parse-crs-from-shapefile-using-geotools)

Any help ?

Comment: Only one of those (.shx) is even part of a shapefile.

Comment: I meant 'Vector GIS File Formats' mentioned here (https://gisgeography.com/gis-formats/).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hi Ian, 

we get spatial data from various GIS file formats (.tab, .mif, .shx, .kml). 
To parse these files, I am using ogr2ogr command which accepts target CRS and source CRS along with the file which needs to be parsed.
I would like to know the CRS value of the file which I want to pass to ogr2ogr command.

In case of .shx file, using below code, I was able to get the CRS value.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359967/how-to-parse-crs-from-shapefile-using-geotools

But not really sure how I can get the CRS value for the rest of the files.

Please help.

Comment: if there is a CRS set then `ogr2ogr` will find it - if it isn't set in the file then nothing can find this

Comment: Thanks Ian, for your response.
If I pass source CRS as 'EPSG:4326' and file contains easting/northing coordinates (e.g. 436254.82 336370.04) then ogr2ogr throws error 'Failed to reproject feature1 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS)'
But I dont get the same error when I pass source CRS as 'EPSG:27700' and file contains lat/lon coordinates (e.g. -4.13738502,50.40063637). File gets converted to GML format.
If ogr2ogr does not throw any error, does that mean this file is valid for 'EPSG:27700'.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and additional information relevant to your question.

Comment: You can't just make up a projection and hope for the best, you need to check the metadata

Comment: Did you try  ogrinfo? It can report the crs of any gis file. https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html